# Flatten an PHP Array to a simpler structure

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure from a database query:
I extended my previous posts, with more details about the array structure. Hope that helps to better understand my example.

```
array:7 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
            "my_first_key" => "option 1"
            "SUMME" => "6"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
            "my_first_key" => "option 2"
            "SUMME" => "22"
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
            "my_first_key" => "option 3"
            "SUMME" => "37"
        ]
        3 => array:2 [▼
            "my_first_key" => "option 4"
            "SUMME" => "42"
        ]
    ],
    0 => array:4 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
            "my_second_key" => "option 1"
            "SUMME" => "6"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [▼
            "my_second_key" => "option 2"
            "SUMME" => "22"
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
            "my_second_key" => "option 3"
            "SUMME" => "37"
        ]
        3 => array:2 [▼
            "my_second_key" => "option 4"
            "SUMME" => "42"
        ]
    ]
    ...
]
```

How can I transform it to a much simpler structure like:

```
array:8 [▼
    "my_first_key" => array:4 [▼
        "option 1" => "6"
        "option 2" => "22"
        "option 3" => "37"
        "option 4" => "42"
    ],
    "my_second_key" => array:4 [▼
        "option 1" => "6"
        "option 2" => "22"
        "option 3" => "37"
        "option 4" => "42"
    ]
    ...
]
```

I tried to give array_walk_recursive a try, but I can't grab the SUMME key and bind it to the previous option?

```
$tmpArr = [];
array_walk_recursive($data, static function ($value, $key) use (&$tmpArr) {
   $tmpArr[$key][$value] = $value; // not $value? SUMME here?
}, $tmpArr);
```

Comment: What exactly is the logic? Is `my_first_key` always the same? Or is it variable? You want a hierarchy of `$arr[<not the SUMME key>][<not the SUMME key's value] = <SUMME value>`…?

Comment: Yes, my_first_key is always the same ... - in the next array row it is for example - my_second_key ... with exact the same options (1, 2, 3, 4), different sum values ...

Comment: Then you simply want something like `$tmpArr['my_first_key'][$value['my_first_key']][] = $value['SUMME']`…?

Comment: The result should be the second code block I posted for each row from the array. my_first_key => array:4(options), my_second_key => array:4(options)

Comment: ಠ_ಠ I just asked whether `my_first_key` would change or not…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simple do it like below using `foreach()`

```
$tmpArr = [];
foreach($data as $dat){
    foreach($dat as $d){
        $key = array_keys($d)[0];
        $tmpArr[$key][$d[$key]] = $d['SUMME'];
    }
}
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/hmu5r

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use array_walk_recursive you can do it like this:

```php
$output = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function ($item, $key) use (&$output) {
    if ($key === 'SUMME') {
        end($output);
        $a = key($output);
        end($output[$a]);
        $b = key($output[$a]);
        $output[$a][$b] = $item;
    } else {
        $output[$key][$item] = '';
    }
});
```